# Dictionary with Arbitrary Tuple for Key (Without Wrapping in a Class)

Tags: c#, dictionary

In C#, the `Dictionary` class takes a single key and maps it to a single value. I'm looking for something similar, where I can pass in an ordered tuple and get a single value -- *without* wrapping it in a class.

Here's a pretty hypothetical example of what I want (with buttons, instead of some 2D map tile). Currently, I can do this:

```
Dictionary<int, Button> buttons = new Dictionary<int, Button>();
```

If I want to use each button's coordinates as the key, I can do this:

```
Dictionary<Point, Button> buttons = new Dictionary<Point, Button>();
buttons[new Point(b.X, b.Y)] = b;
```

What I would like to do is this

```
Dictionary<int, int, Button> buttons = new Dictionary<int, int, Button>();
buttons[b.X, b.Y] = b;
```

Again, it's a trivial case with a known work-around. But I just find it annoying that I have to create a new placeholder class (struct?) with each set of parameters that I want to use as a key.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Not with arbitrary amount of arguments, not in C# at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class TupleDictionary<T1, T2, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>,TValue>
{
    public TValue this[T1 t1, T2 t2]
    {
        get { return this[new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2)]; }
        set { this[new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1,t2)] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(T1 t1, T2 t2, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2), value);
    }

    public void Remove(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        Remove(new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2));
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        return ContainsKey(new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2));
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(T1 t1, T2 t2, out TValue value)
    {
        return TryGetValue(new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2), out value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not a bad idea actually. Not particularly arbitrary, but it solves the problem.

Comment: @Jay - I didn't realize that you could have multiple arguments on an indexed property. I learn something new every day!

Comment: btw, use Tuple.Create(...) instead of new Tuple<...>(...).

Comment: Thanks! Because my enormous amount of OCD I just renamed the class Dictionary and let the amount of generic parameters decide to pick the default .NET class or this class.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 4 you can use a tuple as the dictionary key

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Button> buttons = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Button>();
buttons[new Tuple<int,int>(b.X, b.Y)] = b;
```

Comment: Alas, this is precisely what I want to avoid. I hope you read my question :o)

Comment: The Tuple is a built in anonymous class, so there's no need to define a struct.  This is your solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation that extension methods may help.

I've written a bunch of dictionary extension methods to allow functions like `GetOrAdd` and `GetOrDefault` that work on standard dictionaries and these help reduce all of the noise in checking if an item already exists in dictionary.

Likewise, you can extend a nested dictionary with extension methods.

So, perhaps you could write code like this:

```
var buttons = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Button>>();

buttons.Add(b.X, b.Y, b);
buttons.AddOrReplace(b1.X, b1.Y, b1);
```

My `Add` method looks like this:

```
    public static void Add<K1, K2, V>(
            this IDictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, V>> @this,
            K1 key1,
            K2 key2,
            V value)
    {
        if (@this == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("@this"); }
        if (key1 == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("key1"); }
        if (key2 == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("key2"); }
        if (!@this.ContainsKey(key1))
        {
            @this[key1] = new Dictionary<K2, V>();
        }
        @this[key1][key2] = value;
    }
```

This kind of approach is nice because you are still working with standard .NET dictionaries, but getting the functionality you're after with only a relatively minor syntax difference.

An alternative approach is to define your own dictionary-like class. Something like this:

```
public class TupleDictionary<K1, K2, V>
{
    public void Add(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value);
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2);
    public bool Remove(K1 key1, K2 key2);

    public Dictionary<K2, V> this[K1 key1] { get; }
}
```

And then, because the `this` indexed property would "get or add" the inner dictionaries, you can write your code like this:

```
var td = new TupleDictionary<int, int, Button>();

td[b.X][b.Y] = b;
```

Syntactically it looks the same as your example code, but you'd need to write a fair amount of code just to get this specific syntax.

I think the extension method approach using nested dictionaries is the way to go.

Comment: Interesting approach of a dictionary within a dictionary. I like it. It saves me from subclassing (see @Jay's answer).